# HTTPStatusEvent support in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

According to [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html) HTTPStatusEvent in some browsers not always working as expected.

> Some Flash Player environments may be unable to detect HTTP status codes; a status code of 0 is always reported in these cases.

Which browsers/versions not supported?